# Unable to deploy a web app to azure portal using publish profile from DevOps Service

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy a simple DotNet core web Application to azure app service using CICD pipeline and I want to deploy the webapp using publish profile. CI is successful and while releasing the pipeline, when I select the connection type as "publish profile" it is expecting a pubxml file at "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.pubxml" this path, and when I click create release it says "there is no package found with specific pattern :D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml".

I have created the publish profile with visual studio and I have committed it to azure repo and still I'm facing the same issue. So, any one help me in resolving this issue.

how to make this .pubxml file available at "D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml" this path.

Note: I have tried in both classic editor(without YAML) and Azure repos git (with YAML). and I have committed the code to azure repo from visual studio community.

Comment: Are you sure your *.pubxml gets copied to the output folder? The r1\a directory contains the release artifacts, so even though the publish profile is in your input (committed to git) it doesn't necessarily wind up with the output for a release.

Comment: I'm sure that I have committed the .pubxml files to azure repo and after building the pipeline an artifact is getting generated which contains only one .zip folder. next while releasing the pipeline after selecting the connection type as: publish profile, in publish profile path by default it is taking "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.pubxml" path. and there is also a browse option to .pubxml file, if I click that I could see only the path to .zip file not the .pubxml file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path carefully.  Instead of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/.pubxml`

you probably meant:
`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.pubxml`

Also keep in mind your .gitignore file likely contains this line: `*.pubxml`
which prevents adding .pubxml files to your repository.

Comment: Even after commenting the line: *.pubxml from the gitignore file, I'm getting the same issue and is there any other lines to comment from gitignore file to resolve the issue? I'm getting the following error : Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\.*.pubxml<br>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

Comment: from the error statement it is expecting  the .pubxml file at "D:\a\r1\a**\*.pubxml" path, How to add the .pubxml file to expected path??

Comment: I successfully find my publish profile by starting in this location: $(build.sourcesDirectory)

Comment: After using the location: $(build.sourcesDirectory), I was able to see the publish profile, but this time I'm getting some other error --->error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.deploy.cmd                                                                   --->how to get this *.deploy.cmd ??

Answer (score 0):

try this one: "../../**/*.pubxml"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.